# Rails 3.1.3 jquery ajax not working in separate .js file

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, assets

I am relatively new to Rails. I have the following jquery code:

```
    //used in my.html.erb
    $('#category_id').change( function() {
      var theURL = "/requests/byCategory/" + $('#category_id').val()
      $.ajax({url: theURL,
        success: function(data){
         $('#displaySelection').html(data);
        }
      })
    });
```

When I have it nested in a script tag within the erb it works. When I move the above jquery code to app/assets/javascripts/my.js it does not work. The app/assets/javascripts/application.js looks like:

```
    //= require jquery
    //= require jquery_ujs
    //= require_tree .
```

Obviously, I do not correctly understand the assets pipeline. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Did you embed your change callback into `$(document).ready`?

If not it shouldn't be a matter of the asset pipeline, but of DOM loading.

## 'app/assets/javascripts/my.js'

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#category_id').change( function() {
    var theURL = "/requests/byCategory/" + $('#category_id').val()
    $.ajax({url: theURL,
      success: function(data){
       $('#displaySelection').html(data);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

## 'app/assets/javascripts/application.js'

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require_tree .
```

Comment: Yep, that was it. Was not thinking about the DOM being fully loaded. Thanks!